# htaccess rewrite rules without R flag creating external redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm doing what I thought was a simple .htaccess rewrite to create nicer urls.  I want a url like this:

```
http://my-site.com/design/design-name/
```

to replace urls like this:

```
http://my-site.com/store?design=design-name
```

so I added this rule to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^design/(.+) http://my-site.com/store?design=$1 [L]
```

However, it is behaving as if there is an R flag and **externally** redirecting (changing the url in the browser's address bar).  The redirection works fine, but shouldn't it be only **internally** redirecting with the rule I'm using?

Comment: Remove `http://my-site.com/` from the RewriteRule and leave just `store?design=$1 [L]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansari is correct. As mentioned [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3784628.htm), including a domain name in the target URL turns it into a 302 redirect. Change

```
RewriteRule ^design/(.+) http://my-site.com/store?design=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^design/(.+) store?design=$1 [L]
```

and it should work correctly.